# k8s | networking between two pods

Tags: networking, kubernetes, vpn

I would like since a pod containing a simple container (nginx, php, nodejs, etc ...) able to route all calls to an IP address to another pod that contains a container openvpn client.

What i do:
(pod subnet in 10.2.0.x)

- ping from the pod openvpn client the other pod => ok
- ping from the php pod the pod openvpn client => ok
- ping my destination (10.30.x.x) from the pod openvpn client => ok
- after add route, ping my destination (10.30.x.x) from the php pod => NOT OK

I have already tried to add routes, but nothing to do.

Do you think it's possible to do what I want?
I simply wish to route 10.30.x.x from php directly to openvpn pod

Comment: What is `ip route get <destination_ip>` showing when you run it on your `php pod` ?

Comment: thx for your response.
I have this:
`10.30.13.1 via 169.254.1.1 dev eth0 src 10.2.0.52
    cache`

Comment: And what about pinging 10.2.0.52 ? Does it work ?

Comment: yes it's works.
For you, is it possible to do that ? I use the OVH public cloud

Comment: Sorry, I meant pinging 10.30.13.1. Are you able to ping it ? No, I cannot do that as these are your private addresses. So what about this statement: `after add route, ping my destination (10.30.x.x) from the php pod => NOT OK` ? What is the result of `ip route get <destination_ip> for the IP address you say you are not able to ping ?

Comment: Sorry for my very late response.
But i've had no time to continue my research :/
So i've take the decision to go back on Docker, and everything works :)

Thx for you help @mario